# How can Viewbox/Canvas/Path elements be retrieved for Coded UI testing?

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

When performing Coded UI tests on a WPF application, a WPF button I need can be found in the following way:

```
WpfButton button = new WpfButton(mainWindow);
button.SearchProperties[WpfButton.PropertyNames.AutomationId] = "btn";
button.WindowTitles.Add("MainWindow");
```

After this initialization I can successfully perform any checks and validations.

The problems begin when I'm trying to check the state of a ViewBox element, which contains a Canvas, which, in its turn, contains a Path. No one of these elements has an analog type from the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WpfControls` namespace. After a short investigation I've found out that these types also don't have `OnCreateAutomationPeer` method overridden.

So, what is the most convenient way to retrieve a Canvas or a ViewBox, or a Path for UI testing?

Maybe, I've missed the compatible type from the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WpfControls` namespace or, maybe, I should derive the custom type (for example, from a Canvas) and override the `OnCreateAutomationPeer` method in it, and then create an automation peer for my DerivedCanvas class? I'm a newcomer to the Coded UI testing, so if the second solution solves the problem, how can it be implemented?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you not using a UI map? At the very least, you can investigate the generated code to see how it's getting to those elements.

Comment: @DanielMann Do you mean the code generated by Coded UI Test Builder utility? Unfortunately, it can't "see" a Canvas. If I, for example, click the Canvas contained in the Window, it will recognize only Window. But for such elements as TextBlock or Button all will be ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer. It appears to be very simple. First, a new `AutomatisableCanvas` class should be derived from `Canvas`:

```
public class AutomatisableCanvas : Canvas
{
    protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        return new CanvasAutomationPeer(this);
    }
}
```

Second, a new `CanvasAutomationPeer` class should be derived from `FrameworkElementAutomationPeer`:

```
class CanvasAutomationPeer : FrameworkElementAutomationPeer
{
    public CanvasAutomationPeer(Canvas owner)
        : base(owner) { }

    protected override AutomationControlType GetAutomationControlTypeCore()
    {
        return AutomationControlType.Custom;
    }
}
```

And now an `AutomatisableCanvas` control can be simply found as follows:

```
WpfCustom canvas = new WpfCustom(mainWindow);
canvas.SearchProperties[WpfCustom.PropertyNames.AutomationId] = "an AutomationId you've specified for an AutomatisableCanvas instance";
canvas.WindowTitles.Add("MainWindow");
```